# Initialize schema and domain on JDBC H2 Connection String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I want to initialize both schema and domain for my in-memory h2 database for running Junit test cases but I face the below error. Is there a proper syntax to initialize both schema and domain on init?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS INVENTORY CREATE[*] DOMAIN IF NOT EXISTS JSON AS TEXT"; SQL statement:
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS inventory create domain if not exists json as text [42000-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:229)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:1051)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:741)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:241)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:171)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:166)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:29)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:340)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:173)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:152)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
```

My property file for  in-memory h2 database is below.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS inventory create domain if not exists json as text;MODE=PostgreSQL;
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 SQL statements without separator ...

According to http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection you may use '\;':

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS inventory\\; CREATE DOMAIN IF NOT EXISTS JSON AS TEXT;MODE=PostgreSQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be:

Create a file called `schema.sql` with whatever statements you need at init time, and save this file to `test/resources`

In my case, I needed to define a domain like `create domain timestampstz as timestamp` needed only at unit test time, since H2 doesn't have that data type.